# ProcessPoolExecutor cannot execute my own functions but executing print works

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    p.submit(lambda x: print(x), "something")  # doesn't work
    p.submit(print, "something")  # works fine
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Why does this make sense?

Comment: please post the exact error message

Comment: The function to be called has to actually exist in each process, with the same globally-defined name, in order for the call information to be transferred to the process that will actually execute it.  Here, you're only defining it in the main process, and don't have a global name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check the [result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) of the future you will see the relevant error message:

```
>>> from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
>>> p = ProcessPoolExecutor()
>>> p.submit(lambda x: print(x), "something").result()
...
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x113eec5e0>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

So this error message is pretty self-explanatory if you're familiar with how a process pool executor works. But if you're not, then there might be some more explanation needed: the process will try to access the worker function by name, but since lambdas are "anonymous" functions they don't have a valid name to look up in the module namespace.

```
>>> (lambda x: print(x)).__name__
'<lambda>'
```

As a workaround, you could use a [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) multiprocessing pool which uses [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill), a more powerful serialization library than [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Unlike pickle, dill is able to serialize lambdas. The `ProcessPool` interface in pathos is a little different to stdlib multiprocessing `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but the closest analogy to your simple `submit` usage would be a `pipe`:

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
>>> p = ProcessPool()
>>> p.pipe(lambda x: print(x), "something")
something
```

If you're curious how dill is able to dump lambdas, turn on the tracing and check out what it actually does with this snippet:

```
import dill.detect
dill.detect.trace(True)
dill.dumps(lambda x: print(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

`ProcessPoolExecutor` wants to pickle the function, but since a lambda has no name, it cannot be found to get pickled.

For example:

```
from pickle import dumps

def fun(x):
    print(x)

lmb = lambda x: print(x)

dumps(fun)  # succeeds
dumps(lmb)  # fails
```

So, this will work just fine:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def fun(x):
    print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    lmb = lambda x: print(x)
    p.submit(lmb, "lambda")  # works fine
    p.submit(fun, "local function")  # works fine
    p.submit(print, "built-in function")  # works fine
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

But if you replace the `ThreadPoolExecutor()` with the `ProcessPoolExecutor()`, which will need to pickle the function, the lambda stops working.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    lmb = lambda x: print(x)
    future = p.submit(lmb, "lambda")  # doesn't work
    print(future.result())
```

This shows that the problem does indeed occur when pickling, and it also makes clear why:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x00000294E66B3E20>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

`__main__` is the main process, which does not have the lambda in its namespace, because a lambda itself is nameless. Assigning it to a variable like `lmb` doesn't change that, since the lambda is dereferenced from the variable. The other two functions inherently have a name in the namespace of `__main__`, and can be pickled.

Note that `__main__` is the same name you'd test for in:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: So pickling is not needed when I use a ThreadPoolExecutor because it's within the same process so it has access to the memory, right?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey yes, more or less. The threads all run within the same process and so data can be passed around without pickling. With the ProcessPoolExecutor, it will be running in an actual different process, so everything is pickled to be able to send it over and add it to that process.